# Making a text input just strings and no code

Tags: php, html, css

I Have a problem.

I am making a live chat out of php (I am new to php), and it takes your name, `$theName`, and `theMessage`, and it writes it to a txt file and then reads the txt file and displays it on index.php. My problem is that in the message box, you could write something like `<b style="color: green;">Hello</b>` and it would make that message green. How do you make it so that the user can't put code in the input, and instead just a plain string?

Here is a segment of my php:

```
$handle = fopen("view.txt", "a");
fwrite($handle, $theName . " - " . $theMessage . "\n"); //this is where you can put code that I don't want
fclose($handle);
$theName = NULL;
$theMessage = NULL;
echo $emptyLink;  //the index.php
```

Comment: This is called a XSS vulnerability. And it is prevented by using [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Comment: ok. so how would I imply that to my code?

Comment: That blue text is a link which can be clicked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have *wysiwyg* plug-ins that make it right (e.g : TinyMCE).
Include it in you chat system and it will make it for you.

But if you insists, `htmlspecialchars()` will allow you to have a string that is not readable as HTML but as string. Then you can play with it in the processing.

Comment: This helped. I am working on it in my php right now!